# use regular expression in a join condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to join 2 tables.Table ABC has server name as oracle123 in build_cluster_name,while table XYZ has server name as oracle123.us.oracle.com  in host_name column.
Using the below SQL to achieve it ,but it fails.Please suggest.Thanks.

```
select * from ABC p
join XYZ g on p.build_cluster_name=g.regexp_substr(host_name, '^[^.]+')
```

Comment: just use like: `on g.host_name like p.build_cluster_name||'.%'`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `g.` is in the wrong place.

```
WITH
    abc AS (SELECT 'oracle123' AS build_cluster_name FROM DUAL),
    xyz AS (SELECT 'oracle123.us.oracle.com' AS host_name FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM ABC p JOIN XYZ g ON p.build_cluster_name = REGEXP_SUBSTR (g.host_name, '^[^.]+')
```